# Cleaning up connection pool before Java process exit

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling, c3p0

I have a java application that gets called from a script every few minutes. The flow is:

1. Script invokes java process every few minutes.
2. The java program runs for a few minutes (sometimes less), do some processing and once completed exits by calling System.exit(0).
3. In step 2, in order to do the processing, we use [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) connection pool to connect to MySQL DB.

Everytime we get the connection from the pool, we call `close()`. We also have `unreturnedConnectionTimeout` set to `20` so that any time a connection is help too long or not closed, c3p0 takes care of it.

My question is, once all the processing in Step 2 is complete, and before we exit by calling `System.exit(0)`, do we need to do any clean up of the connection pool?

I know that calling `close()` with connection pool only returns the connection back to pool and do not actually "close" the connection. So before exiting do I need to do any clean up of the conn pool? If I don't do any clean up and does a JVM exit, does the connections to DB still linger around or does c3p0 cleans/force close them? Thanks!

Comment: The connections cannot survive the JVM process in any case. The operating system will close all open sockets when a process exits, unless you're running on something weird like NetWare 3 or 4.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an instance of [`com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PooledDataSource`](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/PooledDataSource.html) (e.g. [`com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource`](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource.html) ), you can use the method [`com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources.destroy()`](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/DataSources.html#destroy%28javax.sql.DataSource%29).

This method:

> Immediately releases resources (Threads and database Connections) that are held by a C3P0 DataSource.
>
> Only DataSources created by the poolingDataSource() method hold any non-memory resources. Calling this method on unpooled DataSources is effectively a no-op.
>
> You can safely presume that destroying a pooled DataSource that is wrapped around another DataSource created by this library destroys both the outer and the wrapped DataSource. There is no reason to hold a reference to a nested DataSource in order to explicitly destroy it.

```
PooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
// everything you do

DataSources.destroy(dataSource);
System.exit(0);
```

In another way, (again, if you are using an instance of [`com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PooledDataSource`](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/PooledDataSource.html)), the method [`com.mchange.v2.c3p0.PooledDataSource.html#hardReset()`](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/PooledDataSource.html#hardReset%28%29):

> Destroys all pooled and checked-out Connections associated with this DataSource immediately. The PooledDataSource is reset to its initial state prior to first Connection acquisition, with no pools yet active, but ready for requests.

```
PooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
// everything you do

dataSource.hardReset();

System.exit(0);
```

The method `dataSource.close()` is the best choice because it is more obvious. It is always advisable to close the resources. The connection might stay open for a moment in the database, but after the timeout, closes. This behavior depends on the database vendor.

Comment: Thanks Paul! I saw that method. The question is Do I need to call destroy? If I don't call destroy(), what happens to the connections in the c3p0 pool on jvm exit? Does the MySQL Server also drops the connections or does it keep them around? Also which is better: PooledDataSource.close() or DataSources.destroy()?

Comment: You only need the `dataSource.close()` because it is simpler. The method `hardReset()` is is useful for maintenance.